# Display PHP custom field within WordPress shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, shortcode

I'm using the `echo do_shortcode` function to include an events calendar within a WP template. I need to display a custom field within the shortcode area, but can't get it to work. Below is my code. I need the custom field "tickets" to show in the `a href="#"` section (replacing the #).

The post is a custom post type called "event".

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[eo_events] 
<div class="date">
  <div class="month">%start{M}%</div>
    <div class="day">%start{j}%</div>
</div>
<div class="venue">
   <h2 style="margin-bottom:-40px!important; padding-bottom:0;">%event_venue%</h2>
   <br/>%event_venue_address%<br/>%event_venue_country%, %event_venue_postcode%
</div>
<div class="city"><h2>%event_venue_city%</h2></div>
<div class="tickets">
    <h2><a href="#" target="_blank">Tickets</a></h2>
</div>
[/eo_events]');
?>
```

Comment: `<h2><a href="' . $yourcustomfield . '" target="_blank">Tickets</a>` ?

Comment: That didn't do anything, unfortunately. I've tried @Gerald Schneider's answer below too and it hasn't worked either.

Answer (score 0):

get the custom field first and save it in a variable. You can use the variable later in the string.

```
<?php
$url = get_post_meta($post_id, 'tickets', true);
echo do_shortcode('[eo_events] 
<div class="date"><div class="month">%start{M}%</div> <div class="day">%start{j}%</div></div> <div     class="venue"><h2 style="margin-bottom:-40px!important; padding-bottom:0;">%event_venue%</h2> <    br/>    %event_venue_address%<br/>%event_venue_country%, %event_venue_postcode%</div> <div class="city"    ><h2    >%event_venue_city%</h2></div> <div class="tickets">    
<h2><a href="'.$url.'" target="_blank">Tickets</a></h2>    
</div>    
[/eo_events]');
?>
```

Comment: Thanks - however, when I hover over the Tickets link, it just links to the same page and not the URL entered in the custom field box.